# Firebase Cloud Messaging successful sendToDevice but no notification

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write a cloud function which sends a push notification to an iOS device. The logs say that sendToDevice was successful. But my device isn't receiving any notifications. Neither Xcode nor Cloud Functions are showing any errors. How can I diagnose this problem?
My cloud function takes a registration token from the realtime database. This token is saved to the database during the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` function in the ios app, confirming that the front end is registering for remote notifications. The app has been given permission to show notifications and the push notification capabilities have been enabled in Xcode.
This block of code comes from my cloud function **(Node.js)**:

```
// This snapshot was taken from the realtime database
// Xcode logs confirmed that this function is receiving the correct key
const notificationKey = userSnapshot.child("notificationKey").val();

const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'Test Notification Title',
    body: 'Test Notification Body',
    sound: 'default',
    badge: '1'
  }
};

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationKey, payload).then(function (response) {
  console.log("Successfully sent message: ", JSON.stringify(response));
  return;
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
  return;
});
```

When calling the cloud function above, the logs showed this console log (Id numbers truncated):

```
"Successfully sent message:  {"results":[{"messageId":"0:154/* ... */"}],"canonicalRegistrationTokenCount":0,"failureCount":0,"successCount":1,"multicastId":576/* ... */}"
```

But my test device (iPhone 7) hasn't received any notifications. My app has the following delegate functions **(Swift 4)**:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    print("Notification will present: \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("Notification received: \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}
```

Neither print statement is appearing in Xcode's output. The only relevant print statements found are the ones I included in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. My APNs certificate is apparently still valid and has not expired.

Comment: Are you able to receive a message using the [test on device feature of the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification/compose)? Put the registration token in where it says "test on device" and see if you receive it. That will help narrow the issue to client or server code. Also, have you [uploaded your APNs key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#upload_your_apns_authentication_key)?

Comment: The test feature on the Firebase console proceeds without any error, but no notification arrives on the device. I have confirmed that the APNs key on the Apple Developer account matches Firebase.

Comment: Is the app in the background when you send the notification? Does the team ID for the Firebase app match the one from Apple?

Comment: I double-checked the team ID to confirm that it matches. Sending the notification with the app open and in the background yielded the same results. The cloud function logs show a successful notification sent, but no reaction from the device. Is there some way to view the lifecycle of the payload on Apple's end? Between when it leaves Firebase and arrives at the designated device?

Comment: Having same issue on iOS

Comment: Are u subscribing to a topic? Did you try to send the notification directly to your deviceToken? Did you implemented the delegate methods needed, also Did you ask for user permission and registered you app to receive remoteNotifications?

Comment: I haven't used topics. The code in my question includes the cloud function which uses a registration token to send a payload to a device, and the delegate functions in my Xcode project. My app requested permission to receive remote notifications and I allowed it.

Comment: Updated information from testing: I used a third party program (https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) to manually send push notifications to my device and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` successfully received and parsed the notification payload. But I'm still getting no reaction from Firebase-sent notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply that my podfile was missing:

```
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

That allowed my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to receive the notification payloads from Firebase cloud function. Then once I added `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` to the AppDelegate, the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` functions worked as intended.

Strange how the missing pod didn't give me any compiler errors.

Comment: I had a similar issue that was caused by the missing pod and I agree, a compile error would have been useful

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue, I've checked the pods and they seem to be fine. What could be the issue that iOS is not receiving the notifications?